# "Find My iPhone" locked my Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, find-my-mac

Yesterday my MacBook Pro started to be blocked.

When it boots it asks for the password for the Guest account. No password is right. According to various sources of information I found on the Web, this may mean that the computer has been locked from iCloud using "Find My iPhone".

From https://www.icloud.com/#find the Macbook seems to be blocked:

[image]

But there is no "unlock" button on iCloud:

[image]

When I click "Play Sound" a sound is effectively played by the Macbook:

[image]

"Find My iPhone" is not able to locate the computer's location, but it is here, on my desk!

When I power off the MacBook Pro something changes on https://www.icloud.com/#find and a button "Remove from Account" appears. After I clicked that button the MacBook Pro is removed from the device listing. But as soon as I reboot the Macbook will reappear in the listing.

I don't understand what is wrong: I own the computer, I own the iCloud/Apple ID account but I can neither use it, nor unlock it.

I tried to call Apple, today they won't respond (today it's Sunday, tomorrow is a holiday in my country.) I can't wait till tuesday.

Do you know how to solve my issue?

Comment: It doesn't look locked? Can't you just log in with your mac's user password?

Comment: @KevinGrabher I can't enter my username, only the guest account seems available.

Comment: Isn't that your user that can be seen on the screenshot?

Comment: If you can get into the guest account open system preferences there and check if your user exists in the Users & Groups pane. If yes, activate Fast User Switching and try switching over that way

Comment: I can't get into the guest account, the system asks for a password even for the Guest account.

Comment: What's it say when you enter your iCloud password?

Comment: It behaves like when the password is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22588/discussion-between-andrea-francia-and-kevin-grabher).

Answer (score 2):

Solved following these steps.

1. Removed my macbook from iCloud
2. Followed this guide: http://www.tomsguide.com/forum/id-1317787/unlock-apple-macbook-pro.html